# Using DDR4 SDRAM in a Supermicro X10SRL-F Mobo that wants DDR4 ECC SDRAM?

Tags: memory, supermicro, ecc

Hey so I got my hands on a Supermicro X10SRL-F motherboard, and bought myself a Xeon off ebay, but I neglected to get any ram, (money reasons). I figured however, that I might be able to pick something up from my local Fry's, but they don't seem to have L/RDIMM or ECC SDRAM. My question is, is it possible to put normal consumer DDR4 SDRAM in the board, or does it absolutely HAVE to be ECC DDR4 SDRAM? This is just a home project, so that's why I'm not particularly worried about error correction. Nothing particularly important is going to be on this machine.

Specs page in case it's needed:

http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X10SRL-F.cfm

Comment: Sure it will fit the slot, but it won't boot.

Comment: I can't see any way this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only DDR4 Reg ECC RAM and Load-Reduced Reg ECC RAM will work.

Refer this link for compatible memory upgrades for Supermicro X10SRL-F Motherboard

http://www.memorystock.com/memory/SuperMicroX10SRLF.html